# Apache Ignite: Failed to create string representation of binary object

Tags: java, ignite

I am getting below exception and not able to figure out what is wrong with the code.

I have simplified my pojo classes which are to be persisted to ignite cache, but still the complexity remains.

All my pojos are serializable but few of them have business logic code, dao, application context object. These objects can't be removed. Removing these things from the code will require whole code refractoring.

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to create string representation of binary object.
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.tostring.GridToStringBuilder.toStringImpl(GridToStringBuilder.java:1022)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.tostring.GridToStringBuilder.toString(GridToStringBuilder.java:864)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearSingleGetResponse.toString(GridNearSingleGetResponse.java:317)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1162)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1209)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter$6.apply(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:1003)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter$6.apply(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:938)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:385)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.listen(GridFutureAdapter.java:355)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.processNearSingleGetRequest(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:938)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$300(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:135)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$4.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:257)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$4.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:252)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1056)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:581)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:380)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:306)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:101)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:295)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1569)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1197)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:127)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1093)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.StripedExecutor$Stripe.body(StripedExecutor.java:505)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to create string representation of binary object.
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectExImpl.toString(BinaryObjectExImpl.java:189)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.toString(BinaryObjectImpl.java:920)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridStringBuilder.a(GridStringBuilder.java:101)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.tostring.SBLimitedLength.a(SBLimitedLength.java:88)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.tostring.GridToStringBuilder.toString(GridToStringBuilder.java:939)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.tostring.GridToStringBuilder.toStringImpl(GridToStringBuilder.java:1005)
... 27 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to read field: currentContacts
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.wrapFieldException(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:446)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.unmarshalField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:343)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.field(BinaryObjectImpl.java:626)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectExImpl.toString(BinaryObjectExImpl.java:225)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectExImpl.toString(BinaryObjectExImpl.java:186)
... 33 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadOptimized(BinaryUtils.java:1765)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.unmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:1971)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.unmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:1796)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.unmarshalField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:340)
... 36 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: [clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6, err=Failed to deserialize object [typeName=java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap]]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:237)
at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadOptimized(BinaryUtils.java:1762)
... 39 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize object [typeName=java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObject0(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:350)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:198)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:425)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:228)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readSerializable(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:607)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.read(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:954)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObject0(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:346)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readSerializable(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:604)
... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.qm.controller.beans.WorkItem
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8771)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:349)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshallerUtils.classDescriptor(OptimizedMarshallerUtils.java:264)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObject0(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:341)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:198)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:425)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.readObject(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1445)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that your client and Ignite server use the same version of `com.interactcrm.qm.controller.beans.WorkItem` class?

Comment: BTW does **interactcrm** in full class name says that this is a piece of code base of interactcrm?

Comment: Client and ignite server with same version of WorkItem class,Please clarify? There are no jars deployed on ignite server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should disable `DEBUG` logging. `DEBUG` logging will sometimes try to call toString on objects that does not need to be deserialized (and present as classes) otherwise.

Change global log level to `INFO` to make this issue go away.

Comment: I am sure there is nothing to do with logs or log level. This exception comes, when I try to save the object to ignite cache and it crashes the ignite server. Above log is from ignite server itself

Comment: Unfortunatey, there is. Please try the mentioned solution.

Comment: I have filed an issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12178